# Undeclared identifier: 'OnClick'

Tags: delphi

Why do I get this error msg: Undeclared identifier: 'OnClick'

I'm using Delphi 7 and here's my complete code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SavedOnClick : TNotifyEvent;
begin
  SavedOnClick := TControl(Sender).OnClick;
  try
    // Code which takes some time
  finally
    TControl(Sender).OnClick := SavedOnClick;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Are you sure that the actual error message isn't `[DCC Error] ...  E2362 Cannot access protected symbol TControl.OnClick`?

Comment: This is a terrible way to do what you're doing. An onclick event handler changed to remove the handler and then replace it rather than just (a) disabling an action or a control while it is busy, or (b) returning when busy from the Click method?

Comment: Oh please just disable the action!!

Comment: I don't have access to Delphi right now. I understand that there are ways to disable an action but are there a way to stop a TControl from executing events?

Comment: If you disable an action, the controls associated with it will become disabled, too.

Comment: Sorry, my question was unclear. If not using an action, just assigning a click event, are there a way to stop an event from executing? Without doing what OP has done.

Answer (score 10):

When casting, use `TButton` instead of `TControl`. The `OnClick` property of the `TControl` is protected.

Comment: @Wim - It seems that you've lost the question while reading the discussion on this page. Andreas is answering the question *"Why do I get this error msg: Undeclared identifier: 'OnClick'"*, the answer is certainly not *"because you're using 'TControl' instead of 'Button1'*.

Comment: Sertac, what you're missing is that the event is called `TForm1.Button1Click` which suggests it has a control named Button1. So, use the Button1 object or whatever it's renamed to instead of casting...

Comment: @Wim - Q: *"Why do I have this error while casting?"* - A: *"Don't cast!"*. Good one!

Answer (score 2):

If you look at TControl the OnClick property is defined as protected.  IE it is not visible except to descendant classes.  There are two simple ways around this, first would be to use TButton(Sender).OnClick the second would be to create a hack class that you can use to get to the property:

```
type
  TControlOnClickHack = class(TControl)
    published
    property OnClick;
  end;
```

Then use TControlOnClickHack(Sender).OnClick

Warning, make sure your senders have an onClick event before you decide to use the later idea.  TypInfo supplies a function called IsPublishedProp that would be a good idea to use before you attempt to unset/set the property.

Comment: No need to hack anything, you know the control is a Button and as `TButton` the property is obviously published, since it's visible in Object Inspector. You should cast the Sender as `TButton`.

Comment: True, but just in case he wants to use it with controls other than the button.  I've seen plenty of people prefer to call the event handler directly from say an OnKeyDown event when Enter is pressed than to call the .Click procedure of the button itself.

Comment: -1, no need to Hack the control, no matter what type it is. If you were able to assign it's OnClick (at design time OR at run time) then it's OnClick property must be published or public, you should cast to the actual type of the control. Give me an example of a type where you actually need to cast to `TControlOnClickHack` because casting to the actual type doesn't expose `OnClick`.

Comment: @Cosmin - why do you assume that the event will ALWAYS be generated by a TButton ?  Just because the default event handler has been generated by the IDE from an associated button you have no way what-so-ever of knowing that this handler might not be invoked from some other control class.  Indeed, I would suggest that the very fact that the OP is casting to TControl, and not TButton already, strongly suggests this possibility.  Using a helper (not "hack") class avoids having to use RTTI to "discover" the presence of an OnClick event.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a class that extends **TControl** in the same unit as the code that wishes to access the protected members (**OnClick** is protected in **TControl**).

Since the new class is in the unit, we have direct access to it's protected members from other classes in that same unit.  it doesn't (and I would say "shouldn't") need to be in the **interface** as it is strictly an **implementation** detail of your unit:

```
  unit ... ;

interface

  :

implementation

  :

type
  TControlHelper = class(TControl);


// Now we can type-cast to the "helper" class to gain access
//  to the protected members of the ancestor:

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SavedOnClick : TNotifyEvent;
begin
  if Sender is TControl then
    SavedOnClick := TControlHelper(Sender).OnClick;

  try
    // Code which takes some time

  finally
    if (Sender is TControl) then
      TControlHelper(Sender) := SavedOnClick;
  end;
end;
```

Notice that when checking the type of **Sender** we check for an instance of the desired *ancestor* class since it will not ever be an instance of our helper class itself.  Any object that *is* a **TControl** can be safely accessed as a **TControlHelper**, regardless of what actual derived class it may be an instance of.

For this reason I disagree that this is a "hack", as that has negative connotations that I don't think should apply - nothing here is unsafe or liable to break.  It is a technique that takes advantage of language features, nothing more.

NOTE: I called this class **TControlHelper** but it is NOT a "class helper" as defined and implemented in Delphi 2007 (?) and later, although it has about 90% in common in terms of what you can achieve and in fact imho is safer than those "real" helpers.

Also you can clean up the typecasting by exploiting the **absolute** keyword, as long as you keep the type checking in place this is perfectly (well, just as safe as hard casting), functionally identical and much cleaner to read imho:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  control: TControlHelper absolute Sender;
  SavedOnClick : TNotifyEvent;
begin
  if Sender is TControl then
    SavedOnClick := control.OnClick;

  try
    // Code which takes some time
  finally
    if (Sender is TControl) then
      control.OnClick := SavedOnClick;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: -1 for the same reason I downvoted jdarling's: No need for such elaborate hacks when you can simply cast to `TButton`. And your hack is even more elaborate then jdarling's, you're using the `absolute` keyword where a plain hard cast would do.

Comment: You quite simply should not have downvoted according to your own rules as stated in your profile: "I only consider downvoting questions that are wrong.".  Ooops: Neither mine nor jdarlings answers are "wrong", they just aren't how you would do it - you personally would prefer to direct type cast to an assumed class; a real HACK imho.  But we don't get the opportunity to downvote your approach because you haven't bothered suggesting it as an answer yourself, preferring instead merely to criticise others, unfairly imho.  Poor show.

Comment: Do you honestly believe the OP has linked `Button1Click` to the `OnClick` handler of a Label and is now considering ways to generically make that nil for the time it takes to execute that code? And if you want to go there, what if the OP actually assigned `Button1Click` to the `OnTimer` event of a `TTimer`? And by the way, what you implemented here is an unnecessarily complicated take on the "protected hack". No need for the `absolute` keyword, no need for the `control` local variable. You can simply use a hard-cast of `Sender` to `TControlHelper`.

Comment: What I believe isn't really relevant - I certainly don't believe that the OP is writing *my* code, so I choose to answer in a way that appears to suit the *OP'S* code, not my own.  And if you look, you will see that I included both approaches in my answer - did you read it in full before leaping to hit the downvote button ?  Sure, it is not *necessary*, but some might find it *preferable* since it is a cleaner, clearer, functionally equivalent approach.  Do you always qualify references to member variables with "self" ?  If not, why not?  Leaving off "self" is unnecessary.  End.